# After saving remove the value from the field

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

I worked with save and new functionality. When i click <kbd>save and new</kbd> the record get saved but the field doesn't get blank.
I need after i click <kbd>save and new</kbd>, the record need to get saved and field need to blank. so we can enter another record.

This is my code

```
<apex:page standardController="Bank__c" extensions="custom">
  <apex:form >
     <apex:pageblock id="pb" >
        <apex:pageblocktable value="{!Bank__c}" var="ban" >
           <apex:column headerValue="ifsc code">
              <apex:inputfield value="{!ban.IFSC_Code__c}"/>
           </apex:column>
        </apex:pageblocktable>
     </apex:pageblock>
     <apex:commandButton action="{!savenew}" value="Save and New" rerender="pb"/>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

===Controller===

```
public with sharing class custom {
    public Bank__c ban { get; private set; }

    private ApexPages.StandardController sController;
    private String queryString;
    public custom (ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        sController = controller;
        ban = (Bank__c)controller.getRecord();


    }
    public Pagereference SaveNew() {

        upsert ban;

        string s = '/' + ('' + ban.get('Id')).subString(0, 3) + '/e?';
        return new Pagereference(s);


    }
}
```

What's wrong with my code.?
note:
Record  get saved but field doesn't get blank

Comment: What field are you expecting to be blanked out? Your `SaveNew` method does nothing other than save the `ban` record and return a page reference to the edit screen for that record.

Comment: I need IFSC code of my bank object need to empty once i saved

Comment: You need it to be empty or you need the logic to save the current bank object and then create a new one with the IFSC code blank on it?

Comment: once after i saved the ifsc code ,the record need to be saved to bank object at the same time ifsc code field need to empty.so that i can enter another ifsc code

Comment: That makes no sense. Your method is called `SaveNew` surely you should be saving and creating a new record?

Answer (score 1):

[This post](http://www.fishofprey.com/2012/03/salesforce-save-and-new-method-for.html) is more detailed example of what you are trying to do.

One thing you are missing is to use [setRedirect](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_PageReference_setRedirect.htm) so that the current view state does not get carried over to the new page.

```
String s = '/' + ('' + ban.get('Id')).subString(0, 3) + '/e?';
PageReference pr = new PageReference(s);
pr.setRedirect(true);  
return pr;
```

You may also need to remove `rerender="pb"` from the commandButton as you want the whole page to refresh as part of the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to have a workflow and field update to reset the field. This would remove the need to custom code.

Otherwise I'd put the functionality in a trigger.

Doesn't make sense to clear the value in a controller *before* its got to the DB - might as well not bother setting it at all.... (Obviously you may have other functional requirements I'm not aware of.)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a error:

```
        upsert ban;

        **string s = '/' + ('' + ban.get('Id')).subString(0, 3) + '/e?';**
        return new Pagereference**(s)**;
```

After saving the record, you are returning himself in edit mode. You need to change the pagereference to reload screen without the id of the record.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to reinitialize the object after upserting.

```
public Pagereference SaveNew() {

        upsert ban;
        ban = new Bank__c();

        string s = '/' + ('' + ban.get('Id')).subString(0, 3) + '/e?';
        return new Pagereference(s);


    }
```